# Mule esb: is "rolling" log files a default behavior?

Tags: mule, mule-esb

I have mule `3.8.1`. I can see logs for each app I have in `%MULE_BASE%/logs/%MULE_APP%.log` just like defined in `wrapper.conf` file. Example log files I have are:

1. `mule-app-APP1.log.2020-04-07`
2. `mule-app-APP1.log`
3. `mule-app-APP2.log.2020-04-07`
4. `mule-app-APP2.log`

I understand that by default logs are created in the format `%MULE_APP%.log` where `MULE_APP` is `mule-app-<app_name>`.

My question is about "rolling" files. I mean, creating a new log file each day. There is `log4j2.xml` in the project but there is only `AsyncRoot` appender pointing out to `Console` appender. My question: **is the "rolling" log files behavior default in mule ? or there must be a configuration set in the project by someone else, that I'm missing ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not Mule behaviour. This is log4j2 behaviour which is defined in the log4j2.xml file. If you have definition like this

```
<RollingFile name="file" fileName="${sys:mule.home}${sys:file.separator}logs${sys:file.separator}myApp.log" 
         filePattern="${sys:mule.home}${sys:file.separator}logs${sys:file.separator}myApp-%i.log">
    <PatternLayout pattern="%-5p %d [%t] [event: %X{correlationId}] %c: %m%n" />
    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
</RollingFile>
```

which is generate automatically when you create myApp mule Application then you will alwyas have only 10 latest rolling logs.
If you elimate **fileName** like this

```
     <RollingFile name="file"
filePattern="${sys:mule.home}${sys:file.separator}logs${sys:file.separator}myApp-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%-5p %d [%t] [event: %X{correlationId}] %c: %m%n" />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>
```

then you will have behaviour like you described with infinite rolling logs.

See more about this here https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/RollingLogFiles.html